# Centering the container of divs

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center container of divs (gray boxes) so that A=B. This equality should be preserved during resizing of the browser windows. Also, when the window is smaller then the width of current number of divs in a row, div arrangement should change to less number of columns.

I was trying to find some code, but no luck. Hope that someone could help.

[image]

And this is the code I have for now

HTML:

```
<div id="Area">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Area {
    padding: 30px 50px; /* top and bottom 25px, left and right 50px */
}

#container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
    display: inline-block;
   margin: 7 auto;
   width: 350px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: gray;
   border: 1px black solid;
}
```

UPDATE.

After Shai's help, I've come up to a new problem. Divs are now stacked liked this:

[image]

But I would like to have them like this:

[image]

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Can you use flex boxes?

Comment: @ your edit: thats why you don't use something like `text-align` for layouting purposes of boxes like i said in the comment to the answer of Shai. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align: center;` to the `#container`.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c51vnoyd/)

Comment: wouldn't recommend a text property to position a div.

Comment: Also, set `text-align: left` to `.square`s to undo the effect.

Comment: @Razah to position an `inline-block` `div` – why not? Edit: after OP's edit, I agree this solution is no longer perfect (your solution doesn't solve OP's question pre- or post-edit though!)

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix without changing your markup and styles would be to give your `#area` the `position:relative;` and `width:100%` attributes as well as changing the `width:90%` to a full `width:100%` of your `#container`

```
#Area {
    padding: 30px 50px; /* top and bottom 25px, left and right 50px */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8a0035ep/

Comment: @Rayah Problem here is that the container is not centered now.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution(which i prefer most) is to remove `dsiplay: inline-block`(so keep default block) and use `margin: 0 auto`. Also add `margin-bottom` at x px according to your needs.

```css
#Area {
    padding: 30px 50px;
    /* top and bottom 25px, left and right 50px */
}
#container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.square {
    margin: 7 auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Area">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your heard about `media query`. I use the attribute to achieve your purpose.
[This is my JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c51vnoyd/3/) 
**The main code:**

```
@media screen and (min-width:352px){
    #container{
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's almost there. Problem is when you have odd number of divs in the last row they will be centered as well and you are loosing grid format